# Can't display image from external domain on Cordova iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I try to display a Facebook profil picture in my app, but it doesn't work...

I am using the latest version of Cordova on iOS. When I inspect with weinre, I have the correct URL, I can see the picture on my PC but not in the app.

I have the cordova-plugin-whitelist with:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And I have tried with and without this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

But nothing works. Tell me if you need more information.

Thanks for your help, and excuse my English.

Edit: 
Example of URL for img: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=978df650af5b925f321fe4050af2869f&oe=5911542F

my html code for img:

```
<img src="https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=978df650af5b925f321fe4050af2869f&oe=5911542F">
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the logs?

Comment: No, no error just doesn't show the img

Comment: What's the status in the Network tab for this request? Can you paste an example of the image url?

Comment: i don't find the request in the network... example of url is: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?oh=978df650af5b925f321fe4050af2869f&oe=5911542F

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question:

it never works when i test on phonegap app (on iphone) but if i install my app (on iphone) it works without this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

but if i put this meta it doesn't work.

If someone have an issue to make it works on phonegap app?